# setTimeout [Callback must be a function] error

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I'm working on a simple Node.js register/login, and I want the error message to disappear after 2 seconds.

```
if (password.length < 6) {
  setTimeout(errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters' }), 2000);
}
```

However, I get an error:

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received 2 at setTimeout (timers.js:122:11)

Comment: You're calling `errors.push` *immediately* and are passing whatever it returns (likely nothing) to `setTimeout` to be called later (which obviously fails).

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code as below sir:

```js
if (password.length < 6) {
   setTimeout(function() {errors.push({msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters' })},2000); 
}
```